# Outlook Add in not properly initialised when called from "Send to" Windows contextual menu

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

I work on an Outlook 2016 add-in (C# visual studio 2017 on Windows 10).
The add-in do its job perfectly when a new message is created and then sent from the "Write new message" window launched from the Outlook main menu (or toolbar) : the add-in displays its own ribbon with some radiobuttons to configure the message to be sent and that's all.

But when a new message window is created from the Windows contextual menu "Send to" on a file (to be sent as an attachement), the add-in is ignored : the radio buttons, even if they trigger their respective callbacks and so configure the underlying model, let the new message unchanged :-(

The main difference observed under debugger is :

- from the outlook menu : the "ThisAddIn" class seems to retrieve a wrapper for the new message window and so the configuration is taken into account when the message is sent :-)
- from the Windows contextual menu : only a "GetCustomUI" callback is triggered and so the message is sent unchanged when the "Send" button is clicked :-(

Any help (examples, documentation, howto, ...) appreciated ...

JF

Comment: Could you be more specific? What code do you have in the event handlers? What code is supposed to be running not letting the message go out?

Comment: I will post next week some code (I'm on a second project) ... The message goes out but without the changes the add-in is supposed to do.

Comment: Without knowing what exactly is made in the event handlers of your ribbon (modifications to emails) nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not all event handlers are triggered when users try to send files using the context menu `Send To`.

If the [GetCustomUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonextensibility.getcustomui) is triggered when a user sends files from a folder (using a context menu) you can add a custom ribbon UI with your radio buttons to configure the message to be sent. I suppose that is all what your add-in does.

You just need to use Ribbon XML to create a custom UI and use the `GetCustomUI` function to return it back. Read more about that in the [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) article.

In the ribbon event handlers you need to make sure you get access to the item through the [Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribboncontrol.context) passed as an argument. For example, the `onAction` callback has the following signature:

```
C#: void OnAction(IRibbonControl control)
VBA: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
C++: HRESULT OnAction([in] IRibbonControl *pControl)
Visual Basic: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
```

The `IRibbonControl` interface instance provides the `Context` property which represents the active window containing the Ribbon user interface that triggers a callback procedure. So, you may cast it to the `Inspector` or `Explorer` for retrieving the actual mail item you have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right about what the add-in does : GetCustomUI is triggered by the "Send to" action and provides XML datas for the ribbon. I'm working on 2 projetcs and will explore the link you provided next week :-)

Comment: If the problem is solved I'd recommend marking the post as answered.

Comment: I work on another project and have no time to try further ... for the moment ... But it's not solved :-( Thanks anyway :-)